# Google tag manager: Magento-2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, google-tag-manager

According to this guide http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/marketing/google-tag-manager.html
there should be some options in magento2 2.2.2 to choose google tag manager instead of just google analytics, but in my Magento 2.2.2, I can only choose Google analytics, under store->configuration->sales->Google API->Analytics
I guess I need to install some additional feature, since I upgraded from 2.1.9 to 2.2.2?

Comment: So, how can we set up tags and triggers? Is it possible?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/149192)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have Enterprise Version or Community/Open Source version of Magento? Tag Manager is available in Enterprise version of Magento only. Here is the URL for Open source version of Magento.

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/google-tools.html

Answer (score 2):

I have created a FREE module which provides the feature to add Google Tag Manager on Magento 2.x.

Here's the link of the module: https://marketplace.magento.com/chapagain-googletagmanager2.html

Answer (score 0):

GTM is only available on Magento Enteprise not community version hence you might not be able to see GTM in your Magento 2 admin panel.

Comment: for community you can use this extension https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-2-google-tag-manager-enhanced-ecommerce-tracking.html